# Oracle EBS description column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ebs

Please can you help me how to get description column for each EBS user and responsibility for this query?

```
SELECT
    fu.user_name              "User Name",
    frt.responsibility_name   "Responsibility Name",
    furg.start_date           "Start Date",
    furg.end_date             "End Date",
    fr.responsibility_key     "Responsibility Key",
    CASE
   WHEN furg.end_date IS NULL OR furg.end_date > SYSDATE
     THEN 'ACTIVE'
   ELSE 'INACTIVE'
    END user_status
FROM 
apps.fnd_user_resp_groups_direct furg, 
applsys.fnd_user fu, 
applsys.fnd_responsibility_tl frt, 
applsys.fnd_responsibility fr
WHERE
furg.user_id = fu.user_id
AND furg.responsibility_id = frt.responsibility_id
AND fr.responsibility_id = frt.responsibility_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.. If not, can you be more specific?

```
SELECT
    fu.user_name               "User Name",
    fu.description             "User Description",
    frt.responsibility_name    "Responsibility Name",
    frt.description            "Responsibility Description",
    furg.start_date            "Start Date",
    furg.end_date              "End Date",
    fr.responsibility_key      "Responsibility Key",
    CASE
        WHEN furg.end_date IS NULL
             OR furg.end_date > sysdate THEN
            'ACTIVE'
        ELSE
            'INACTIVE'
    END user_status
FROM
    apps.fnd_user_resp_groups_direct    furg,
    applsys.fnd_user                    fu,
    applsys.fnd_responsibility_tl       frt,
    applsys.fnd_responsibility          fr
WHERE
        furg.user_id = fu.user_id
    AND furg.responsibility_id = frt.responsibility_id
    AND fr.responsibility_id = frt.responsibility_id;
```